# Using group_by with a fixed variable name and a variable name called through a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

suppose I have a function foo and a dataset dat with columns a to z, and value. Let's say I have to group by more than one variable, but one is fixed. For example, I have to group by a and then set another grouping variable (from b to z in `vars([insert variable here])`

One option I've tried is this:

```
      foo <- function(.vars){
dat %>% group_by(a, .vars) %>% summarize(mean = mean(value)) 
    }
```

The next is this:

```
   foo <- function(.vars){
dat %>% group_by(a) %>% group_by_at(.vars) %>% summarize(mean = mean(value)) 
    }
```

This didn't work either, as it grouped by only the .vars variable and not a. The former showed an error message. How do I keep a fixed variable, and a 'called' or 'variable' variable in the same function?

Answer (score 0):

`group_by_at` has been superseded, you can now use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(data, vars){
  dat %>% 
    group_by(across("a", all_of(vars))) %>% 
    summarize(mean = mean(value)) 
}
```

Example using `mtcars` dataset :

```
foo <- function(dat, vars){
  dat %>% 
     group_by(across(c("cyl", all_of(vars)))) %>% 
     summarize(mean = mean(mpg)) 
}

foo(mtcars, "am")

#    cyl    am  mean
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4     0  22.9
#2     4     1  28.1
#3     6     0  19.1
#4     6     1  20.6
#5     8     0  15.0
#6     8     1  15.4

foo(mtcars, c("am", "gear"))

#     cyl    am  gear  mean
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4     0     3  21.5
# 2     4     0     4  23.6
# 3     4     1     4  28.0
# 4     4     1     5  28.2
# 5     6     0     3  19.8
# 6     6     0     4  18.5
# 7     6     1     4  21  
# 8     6     1     5  19.7
# 9     8     0     3  15.0
#10     8     1     5  15.4
```